# What'd be better? To add one more local variable, or to call a method twice in general case?

Tags: java, performance

I have the method which returns `java.util.Date` inside the hibernate-entity class:

```
package ua.com.winforce.loto_partner.commons.db.entity;

@Entity
@Table(schema = "pr", name = "publice")
public class Pr {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "reg_date")  
    private Date regDate;

    //GET, SET
}
```

And in a method I need to create the local variable which will be hold `getRegDate();` value, or to invoke that method twice. What would be more appropriate in that case? I mean, in the first case we're potentially closing the moment when GC will be triggered, but in the first we waste our time to the second method invocation.

Comment: This sounds like it'll be a difference of microseconds. Do you have any reason to think that such tiny performance optimizations are important in this code?

Comment: one may argue that conceptually, this has been addressed in [How would you know if you've written readable and easily maintainable code?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/141010/31260) If your peers keep complaining about your way of doing things, be it one way or another, you better change to make them feel better

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are three reasons<sup>*</sup> to cache a function return in a variable:

- You know or suspect that the function has side effects.
- The function can return different values on every call, and you need a consistent result. Normally this is due to the function having side-effects, but it can also be due to reading volatile data.
- The repeated function call would make the code less clear. This is the "extract explanatory variable" refactoring.

Your example doesn't appear to fit any of these cases.

<sup>*</sup> there is a fourth, but it's reserved for Doug Lea and Martin Thompson, and is arguably a combination of #1 and #2.

Comment: There is another reason: Measurements have shown that the repeated call is causing measurable performance problems.

Comment: `Normally this is due to the function having side-effects, but it can also be due to reading volatile data.` Isn't reading a volatile variable a side effect? It's effectively a form of I/O.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau - I always find that profiling leads to more dramatic code restructuring than simply introducing a variable.

Comment: @Doval - Yes IO is a side-effect. In my original edit I only had two points, but then thought that someone would be sure to call me out on volatile reads. That said, I think that it's important to understand and recognize the difference between what I'll call "active" and "passive" side-effects: the former are caused by your action, the latter are caused by external action. In my experience, most concurrency bugs are a result of the latter, not the former.

Comment: As a general principle, anything that *looks* like a getter should act like a getter -- no side-effects; no lengthy business. If so, the call will probably be optimized anyway. Also never forget: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil." --Donald Knuth